# Issue in urlencodeing GET

Tags: php, get

GET send:

```
http://.../?user=<?php echo urlencode("❤#test#❤");?>
```

PHP:

```
$url = $_GET['user'];
$encode = urlencode($url);
$decode = urldecode($encode);

echo $url."<br />";
echo $encode."<br />";
echo $decode."<br />";
```

Output:

```
❤
%E2%9D%A4
❤
```

**How i can show GET in outputting** `❤#test#❤` **?**

I try copy url:

```
http://..../?user=%E2%9D%A4%23test%23%E2%9D%A4
```

Comment: The first code block won't work as it is because it is not echoing the result: `<? urlencode` VS `<?php echo urlencode` or `<?= urlencode`. Are you sure that's your code?

Comment: İn my code:  `echo  '<a href="../?user='.urlencode($user).'">...</a>`;

Comment: Please post your original code OR verify by testing that the code you post does exactly what you think. Is the rest of the code rewritten, too?

Comment: I just ran `var_dump($_GET)` with your query string (`?user=%E2%9D%A4%23test%23%E2%9D%A4`). The result is: `array(1) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(12) "❤#test#❤"
}`. What I'm saying is: Your problem can not be reproduced. Are you sure that's your code and you really did test that url?

Comment: This is original code, i practicing on example page.

Comment: I replaced `var_dump` with your PHP code, pasted 1:1, not modified. Result: `❤#test#❤ |
%E2%9D%A4%23test%23%E2%9D%A4 |
❤#test#❤`. Linebreaks replaced by `|` by me. Your problem is not reproducable.

Comment: On browser url: `❤%23ZitDavn%23❤` , Copied link: `%E2%9D%A4%23ZitDavn%23%E2%9D%A4` Result: `array(1) { ["steam_id"]=> string(3) "❤" }`